# При клике внутри iframe нужно изменять главный документ

Tags: javascript, iframe

При клике внутри `iframe` по кнопкам нужно добавлять классы к `body` главного документа. Iframe и родительский документ будут на разных доменах
Как это сделать? Возможно ли это вообще?

Вижу подобное реализовано в чате https://chatra.io/ru/
Перерыл код но не могу понять как работает у них это все

Comment: Теоретически, это возможно через обмен сообщениями между `window` родительского и дочернего документов (т.е., из фрейма отправлять команду на добавление классов в родительское окно, где его примет скрипт и выполнит это действие). Метод отправки - `postMessage`, событие при входящем сообщении - `message`. На практике, браузер может запрещать такой обмен.

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, различаются ли домены для iframe и главного окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ
На родительском окне ставим

```js
    function listener(event) {
        if (event.origin != 'https://test') {
            // что-то прислали с неизвестного домена - проигнорируем..
            return;
        }

        if (event.data == 'something') {
           // делаем что-то 
        }


    }



    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", listener);
    } else {
        // IE8
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
    }
```

В iframe следующий код

```js
     top.postMessage("something", "https://test");
```